# How can I change a list in a tuple?

Tags: python, list

I want to change the first list in the tuple below so as to increment each value by 1.

```
matrix = [1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]

matrix = [x+1 for x in matrix[0]]

print(matrix)
```

Upon running that code, I receive a single list [2,3,4,5,6].  I am hoping someone can give me a hint that will make it so that the code returns the rest of the tuple like [2,3,4,5,6],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]

Comment: What is the exact output you want?

Comment: @thefourtheye The expected output should be [2,3,4,5,6],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]

Comment: `matrix = [x+1 for x in matrix[0]], matrix[1], matrix[2]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise that it involves reformulating your question, but if you don't want the property of [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python), then just make it a 2D list. Given that you want to be changing these values, you probably do want it to be mutable.

The code would then be:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
matrix[0] = [x + 1 for x in matrix[0]]
print(matrix)
```

Also, I added in some spaces. It's only a little thing, but [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests spaces after commas and around binary operators like `+`.

Comment: Although the tuple type itself is immutable, its elements may contain mutable elements which can still be modified - depending what the OP wants, it's not necessary to make this a list of lists, instead of a tuple of lists, to make changes to an element.

Comment: I agree, but I thought it might be worth questioning the need for a tuple as another possible answer, given that you and wim have provided the other sensible proposals.

Comment: Appears you guessed the OP correctly - have a +1 :p

Answer (score 3):

You can (ab)use a slice operation, such as:

```
matrix = [1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]
matrix[0][:] = [n + 1 for n in matrix[0]]
# ([2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

This will in-place replace the first list of the tuple rather than create a new tuple and re-bind the `matrix` name - for that use [wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29112239) instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky, because you actually have a tuple not a 2D list:

```
>>> matrix = [1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]
>>> ([1 + n for n in matrix[0]],) + matrix[1:]
([2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```